Accessing user jwt claims in Trino/Presto
How can I configure Trino on an EMR cluster to authenticate users using JWT, ensuring that when a user logs in, they are added to Trino and can only access data associated with their tenant ID? Specifically, I want to set up a rule that restricts the visibility of tables to those that include a workspace_id column, where the value matches the workspace_id parameter in the user's JWT. How can this be achieved using file-based access?. I can see Trino exposes username of user as system property but JWT claims are not available. Since Trino is hosted on EMR cluster, I cannot modify the code of trino or create a new system property in trino for this purpose.
